# Add path to environment PATH variable for Apache (wwwrun) and all users after TEX Live update on openSUSE

Tags: linux, opensuse, apache-2.4

After installation of TEX Live 2013 on (I admit outdated) openSUSE 11.3 (x86_64) I needed to add path `/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux` into PATH environment variables for:

- All users
- Apache

Afters hours of googling I ended up with:

- Creating file `/etc/profile.d/texlive.sh` with content `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux` **did the trick** for the users after computer's restart.
- Adding (as a last) row `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux` into `/etc/sysconfig/apache2` worked for **Apache**.

It works, however I am unsure with 2 things:

1. Was it really necessary to restart server after adding file into `/etc/profile.d`? Isn't there some way to just reload environment?
2. It is correct to change Apache's config file when PATH environment variable is changed? Isn't there way how to simply change this variable before Apache is started?

Thank for any answers!